# BQ google update columns - Exceeded rate limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Scenario is to update column descriptions in tables(About 1500 columns in 50 tables).  Due to multiple restrictions I have been asked to use the bq query command to execute the ALTER TABLE sql for updating column descriptions, thorugh cloud CLI. query -
`` bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \ 'ALTER TABLE `<Table>` ALTER COLUMN <columnname> SET OPTIONS(DESCRIPTION="<Updated Description>")'; ``
Issue is if I bunch the bq queries together for 1500 columns it is 1500 sql statements.
This is causing the standard `Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table` error.
Any suggestions on how to execute it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting the [rate limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables):

> **Maximum rate of table metadata update operations per table**: 5 operations per 10 seconds

You will need to stagger the updates to make sure it happens in batch of 5 operations per 10 seconds. You could also try to alter all the columns in a single table with a single statement to reduce the number of calls required.